# C# Sudoku WPF Application and Design

Tags: c#, grid, cell, draw, sudoku

I have already broadly searched the net upon this topic and still I couldn't find a solution that could at least bring me close to what I am trying to achieve.

I want to create a Sudoku Application in `WPF and C#`, and my main problem is about creating the grid.

The grid itself has to be `9 x 9`, and have an `editable structure textbox-like`, and by that I mean a custom designed grid ( so I could draw the lines like in real sudoku - with thicker lines between blocks and little lines between cells, like in this example:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/8558/2/sudoku.png (cant post images yet)

And I would each field to be functioning textbox-like, so I could input values in there and read them, later making the grid into an array of cells.

`So the question is: What controls to use? 
How to make them textbox-like(considering those are just drawn lines) or how to set their design? 
Also, maybe there's an easier solution to my problem?`

Comment: One approach is a nesting of 3x3 UniformGrid controls. And of course it has [been done](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Building-a-WPF-Sudoku-Game-Part-1-Introduction-to-WPF-and-XAML) before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple, you could always just use textboxes inside grids ... have a 3x3 usercontrol in the main grid, set the borders thickness to 3, and inside each control, have a 3x3 grid with textboxes where the thickness is set to 1, or dashed, or whatever suits you...

This is how your usercontrol will be in xaml:

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition>    </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

And just have 3x3 of them ...